# How can I insert value in a char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list and save the value "Peter" in the first list element. I'm having a problem with the char array. I can't insert "Peter" in it.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    using namespace std;

    struct ListElement{
    char name[20];
    ListElement* next;

    };

   int main ()
   {

   ListElement* first;
   first = new ListElement;
   first -> name= "Peter"; // Array type 'char [20]' is not assignable


   };
```

Comment: try `strcpy` instead.

Comment: You can't assign to an array, only copy to it. Use either [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) (as already mentioned) or use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: Why do you `#include <string>` and then not use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the value of a `char[]` array, you should use the `strcpy` or `strncpy` function, like:

```cpp
strcpy(first->name, "Peter");
```

But, better would be to use the `std::string` type, which you can directly assign:

```cpp
struct ListElement{
    std::string name;
    ListElement* next;
};
```

Then `first->name = "Peter";` is valid code.